# Rank function in MySQL assign a rank

Tags: mysql, sql, rank

I need to assign a rank to TC5 not the id.

```
SELECT a.id, a.user_id, a.tc1, a.tc4, min(a.tc5), a.tc2, b.avatar, c.username, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS Rank
FROM 
treningove_casy a INNER JOIN  
sn_users b ON a.user_id=b.id INNER JOIN
users c ON a.user_id=c.id , (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
WHERE  a.tc2 LIKE  'Motokáry Modrice' 
GROUP BY a.user_id
```

So how is the picture. Please help

[image]

The modified code

```
SELECT x.*, (@curRank := @curRank + 1) as Rank
FROM (SELECT a.id, a.user_id, a.tc1, a.tc4, min(a.tc5) as tc5,
             a.tc2, b.avatar, c.username, 
      FROM sbhgl_chronoengine_chronoforms_datatable_treningove_casy a INNER JOIN  
           sbhgl_jsn_users b
           ON a.user_id = b.id INNER JOIN
           sbhgl_users c
           ON a.user_id = c.id 
      WHERE  a.tc2 LIKE  'Motokáry Modřice' 
      GROUP BY a.user_id
     ) x CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @curRank := 0) params
ORDER BY tc5 DESC;
```

Comment: You need to use `ORDER BY tc5`.

Comment: Your query has a problem because you are selecting non aggregate columns while using `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.id, a.user_id, a.tc1, a.tc4, a.tc2, b.avatar, c.username, 
    (select rank from (SELECT 
        IF (@score=s.tc5, @rank:=@rank, @rank:=@rank+1) rank,
        @score:=s.tc5 tc5s
        FROM treningove_casy s,
        (SELECT @score:=0, @rank:=0) r
        ORDER BY tc5 DESC) s ) as rank
FROM 
treningove_casy a INNER JOIN  
sn_users b ON a.user_id=b.id INNER JOIN
users c ON a.user_id=c.id , (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
WHERE  a.tc2 LIKE  'Motokáry Modrice' 
GROUP BY a.user_id
```

You can try above solution, Hope this will help you.

Comment: You can't have a subquery that returns multiple rows in the `SELECT` list.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help, I entered this code. I got an error:  SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you typically use variables for ranks.  In your case, you would use a subquery.  I find that the variable method doesn't always work with `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT x.*, (@curRank := @curRank + 1) as Rank
FROM (SELECT a.id, a.user_id, a.tc1, a.tc4, min(a.tc5) as tc5,
             a.tc2, b.avatar, c.username, 
      FROM treningove_casy a INNER JOIN  
           sn_users b
           ON a.user_id = b.id INNER JOIN
           users c
           ON a.user_id = c.id 
      WHERE  a.tc2 LIKE  'Motokáry Modrice' 
      GROUP BY a.user_id
     ) x CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @curRank := 0) params
ORDER BY tc5 DESC;
```

Note:  The use of table aliases is good.  It is much easier to understand a query, though, if the aliases are abbreviations for the table names.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help, I entered this code. I got an error: unknown 15 expr_type in SELECT [8]

Comment: @MotoKartCup . . . Does the subquery run?  I don't see anything that would cause an error like that.

Comment: I added the modified code.
still writes error: 15 unknown expr_type in SELECT[8]